# can't access fields through self env browse [Odoo 8]

Tags: python, odoo

I want to hide the create button based on the field "type" of model res.partner, by passing in the active_id from context to fields_view_get.

However, i am not able to access any fields, BESIDES the "id" field. I use logger to log the output/ value of the fields

My code:

```
class sale_order(models.Model):

    _description = 'fields view get'

    _inherit = "sale.order"

    @api.model

    def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):

        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        res = super(sale_order, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)

        active_id = self.env.context.get('active_id', False)            

        customer = self.env['res.partner'].browse(active_id)

        _logger.info('sale__customer.id: %d', customer.id)
        _logger.info('sale__customer.name : %d', customer.name)

        #I am getting output from the first log, but not the second

        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])

        if view_type == 'tree':

            for node_form in doc.xpath("//tree"):

                node_form.set("create", 'false')

        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)

        return res

sale_order()
```

I am getting output from the first log but not the second.

and I can see that customer.name is false but it is actually not.

How can I access the fields in the customer object?

Comment: In `fields_view_get` you don't have access to the record which is opened. You can get the active user but not the record which they are opening.

Comment: but i browse for the record by using the active_id which is the id for res.partner, isn't that suppose to work?

Comment: Does the context have any `active_id` at that point? And if so, are you sure that the `active_id` contains an ID of `res.partner`?

Comment: Yes, the tree view that I wanted to edit will have active_id as it is a filter of res.partner. By the way I realize that it is not feasible because the active_id will not change when i remove the filter. Therefore i will need to find another way to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: which Odoo version are you using for? 'couse in old api, brose return a list of ids [1,2,3,4], you could try using .search() it returns a recordset.